# In Python how to call Parent class function as if I were Parent object

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have a Parent and a Child class, both should execute their own fct in **init** but Child have to execute first the Parent fct :

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fct()

    def fct(self):
        # do some basic stuff
        
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fct()

    def fct(self):
        # add other stuff
```

Problem is that super().init() calls the Child fct and not the Parent one as I would like. Of course I could rename Child function as fct2 but I was wondering if I can do what I want to do without changing names (because fct and fct2 do the same thing conceptually speaking, they just apply on different things). It would be nice if I could call super().__init() *as if were* Parent object.

Comment: The normal way this would be solved is to have `Child.fct()` start by calling `super().fct()`, and get rid of the call in `Child.__init__()`.

Comment: You could call `Parent.fct(self)` in `Parent.__init__` to force that version to be called.

Comment: @jasonharper I prefer not to do that because fct is actually more complicated and contains calls to other functions

Comment: @MarkTolonen I just ask the question to Chat-GPT and "it" gives me the same answer as you!

Comment: This might be an XY problem where you need to rethink the design of your two classes rather than trying to force Python to do something that is not intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of subclassining is this: if you ever need to use a method to the parent class, just do not create it in the child class.

Otherwise, in a hierarchy with complicated classes and  mixins, and you really need the methods to have the same name, there is the name mangling mechanism, triggered by Python when using two underlines `__`  as a method or attribute prefix:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__fct()

    def __fct(self):
        # do some basic stuff
        
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__fct()

    def __fct(self):
        # add other stuff
```

Using the `__` prefix makes Python change the name of this method, both in declaration and where it is used when the class is created (at the time the `class` statement with its block is itself executed) - and both methods work as if they were named differently, each one only accessible, in an ordinary way, from code in its own class.

Some documentation, mainly older docs, will sometimes refer to this as the mechanism in Python to create "private methods". It is not the samething, although it can serve the same purpose in some use cases (like this). The `__fct` method above will be renamed respectively to `Parent._Parent__fct` and `Child._Child__fct` when the code is executed.

## second way, without name mangling:

Without resorting to this name mangling mechanism, it is possible to retrieve attributes from the class where a piece of code is declared by using the `__class__` special name (not `self.__class__`, just `__class__`) - it is part of the same mechanism Python uses to make argumentless `super()` work:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        __class__.fct(self)   # <- retrieved from the current class (Parent)
 
    def fct(self):
        # do some basic stuff
        
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        __class__.fct(self) 

    def fct(self):
        # add other stuff
```

This will also work - just note that as the methods are retrieved from the class object, not from an instance, the instance have to be explicitly passed as an argument when calling the methods.

The name `__class__` is inserted automatically in any methods that use it, and will always refer to the class that has the body were it appears - the class itself will be created  "in the future", when all the class body is processed and the `class` command itself is resolved.

Comment: As I said above I ask Chat-GPT the question and it gave me the same answer as Mark. But I think I still prefer yours. Yes! ;-)

Comment: chatGPT maybe is not ready for the "otherwise" side of things.

Comment: Is it possible that you miss a double underscore after the super() init call? (first way)

Comment: Icopyed and pasted that - and yes, that extra pair of underscores is missing in the code in the question as well.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my post as well. Thanks again!